# Can't place variables into values box in exported Excel dataset

Tags: powerbi

I have a very large and dynamic Power BI dashboard that I have developed that my client user would really like to be able to gain access to in Excel. I have tried two ways to getting it connected:

```
1. In Excel >> Data/Get Data/From Power BI
2. In published Power BI Dashboard menu: Analyze in Excel
```

What it show in Excel looks wonderful if and only if I can place counts or sums into the values box. I keep getting this error and need help fixing: "The field that you are moving cannot be placed in that area of the report."

Please let me know what additional information that I can provide that would be useful. Any insight would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I need to create measures in Power BI to place variables as values in Excel